# Wallch not starting randomly on startup on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wallch

Been trying to get Wallch to start automatically on random mode by using the settings but it doesn't seem to work. Couldn't find much else online. What's the status of this feature and if it doesn't work, is there a hack for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is currently experienced by many people. Until it is solved I will be using [Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/how-to-install/). It works like a charm and supports a few cool features like scrolling over the toolbar icon to go forward or backwards.